# React Router with Electron Blank Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am using React with Electron. Running the React project works after building the react project and compiling it with electron when I use the router like this in a button:

```
const ButtonNo = withRouter(({ history }) => (
<button className="wizardbuttons"
        type='button'
        onClick={() => { history.push('/Institution') }}
>
    Skip Setup
</button>
))
```

However I have a few ajax and jquery methods that I want to navigate with after a success is returned. When I use the window.location to go to another page it works fine with react but when I run it in electron I get a blank page.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {




        $.post("address",
            {

                  // Post data

            },
            function (data, status) {


                if (status == 'success') {



                    //nav to screen on success
                    //works with react but gives a blank page with electron
                    window.location = "./PageIWantToGoTo";

                }


            });

    }
  });
```

How do I navigate in response to a ajax success in React combined with electron? I suspect that electron is handling the path incorrectly when not using the withRouter.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your entire jquery logic in a React component, passing history as props to it and then doing a `history.push` when the ajax succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, bind your ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  "path",

        headers: {


        },
        data: {

        },
        success: function(data) {


            this.setState({
                successfullmessage: true
            });




        }.bind(this),
        error: function(errMsg) {
            console.log(errMsg);
        }.bind(this),
    });
```

inside something like this:

```
 super(props);
    this.state = {

        successfullmessage: false

    }

this.submitclick = this.submitclick.bind(this);
submitclick() {

               // ajax here 

              }
```

Then you can use this.setState inside of the success of the ajax function.

Next, to navigate,  in your render() { } before return you can do this:

```
if (this.state.successfullmessage) {
        return <Redirect to="/MainMenu" />;
    }
```

Because you have updated the state, React will automatically rerender and the Redirect will be executed provided that the boolean has been set to true. This will work with electron because the React Redirect provides paths that are compatible with Electron.